# Paypal Order API capture payment in Angular and NestJS

Tags: paypal

My stack is NestJS and Angular12, I am using the OrderAPI v2.

I succesfully implemented the order flow using an SDK button, but, since I have several payment systems that are activated by a single button "Pay now", I need to avoid SDK in my front end.  Follows the methods I use to create and capture payments, and they works with the SDK button.

```
    async createOrder(value: number): Promise<any> {
    const accessToken = await this.generateAccessToken();
    const url = this.baseUrl+`/v2/checkout/orders`;
    const body = {
        intent: "CAPTURE",
        return_url: process.env.CLIENT+"/success",
        purchase_units: [
            {
                amount: {
                    currency_code: "EUR",
                    value: value.toFixed(2)
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    const headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
    }        
    const obs = this.httpService.post(url, JSON.stringify(body),{headers: headers});
    const response = await firstValueFrom(obs);
    return response.data;
}

    async capturePayment(order: CreateOrderDto, orderId: string): Promise<any> {
    const accessToken = await this.generateAccessToken();
    const url = this.baseUrl+`/v2/checkout/orders/${orderId}/capture`;
    const headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
    }
    
    const obs = this.httpService.post(
        url,
        {},
        {
            headers: headers
        }
    )
    const response = await firstValueFrom(obs);
    if (response.data.success) await this.orderService.createOrder(order)
    return response.data;
}
```

When calling the `createOrder()` function I return the url of the approvation, and in my Front-end I do the redirect to the approve page of Paypal. The problem is that when approving the transaction on the approve url the user is shown a infinite loading page.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Why are you not using the SDK? It is the best way to invoke the approval flow.

Comment: @PrestonPHX Because I need a single button to start the paypal flow OR the stripe flow, and with the SDK this result is not achievable.

Comment: The way it's done is by hiding the div container with the PayPal button when a different payment method is selected, and showing it only when the PayPal method is selected. So it's not a "single" button, but it appears in the exact same spot on the page if desired.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'm using ::before on the div containing the PayPal button to styling the div in order to make it appear exactly like the other button. There is a tiny lag but it works pretty well!